# java: TimeZone in rest api

Tags: java, rest, localization, internationalization, jersey-2.0

In my jersey rest api when a user sends a POST request

```
{
   "user":"john",
   "question":"what was temperature an hour ago"
}
```

a `QuestionProcessor` transforms the String `an hour ago` into `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(UTC)).minusHours(5).format(dateformatter);`

I want to replace the `UTC` default by the users timezone. How can I do that?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think you need to determine the TZ on the client and include it in the request. Is the client a browser with JavaScript in your case or how are you sending the POST-request?

Comment: ok thanks. the client would send that request programmatically.

Comment: Then the client needs to specify the time zone as part of the request, explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> replace the UTC default by the users timezone

Easy:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime then = now.minusHours( 1 ) ;
```

The catch: You must know the user’s time zone name such as `Africa/Tunis`, `Europe/Paris`, `Asia/Kolkata`, `Pacific/Auckland`, or `America/Montreal`.

You need to **reformulate your REST API** to also pass a field for time zone name.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as examples seen above. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

---

By the way, I cannot imagine when calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. That class cannot represent a moment as it purposely lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or time zone. Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]